# python bsoup remove part of text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i tried for several hours now. im able to remove the text (readmore variable, in output "weiterlesen") itself but since im accessing the rest of the text by the "overarching class" i cant bring the part of the text to disappear in the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url1 = "https://www.techpilot.de/servlets/supplier/perfect_profile.jsp?lngCode=de&ckey=A4gxuEGikU16YXWt6RMd"

testvar="br"
page = urlopen(url1)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

if testvar=="br":            
            #branche/br
    readmore=soup.find_all("div",class_="readMore")
    readmore.clear()
    for branche in soup.find_all('div', id="perfectIndustry"):
        
        branchenstring=branche.text
        
        branchenstring=" ".join(branchenstring.split())
        print(branchenstring)
```

output is

```
(...)   weiterlesen
```

but should be

```
(...)
```

(...) as the rest of the output

Comment: As weiterlesen is part of the text, it is going to end up in the branchenstring string. Can't you just remove this word `branchenstring.replace("weiterlesen","") ` ?

Comment: The text seems to be presented as follow : 
Branchen, 
4 empty lines, a list of branches, 4 empty lines, weiterlesen, 4 empty lines 
If removing the word doesn't please your use case, can't you just pick the text after the first 4 empty lines and not the texts after ? Try out using `branche.text.split('\n')` to see if it fits your needs

Comment: the replace command works perfectly thanks a lot and it was so simple i feel stupid haha
im not to sure about the split(\n) yet but i will keep you updated

Comment: feel free to add it as answer so i can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that inside for loop to remove contents from `redMore` class and clear it so you will get desired output

```
for branche in soup.find_all("div",id="perfectIndustry"):
    branche.find("div",class_="readMore").clear()
    branchenstring=branche.text
        
    branchenstring=" ".join(branchenstring.split())
    print(branchenstring)
```

Output:

```
Branchen Maschinenbau allgemein Armaturenbau Automatisierungs- und Steuerungstechnik Automobilindustrie und Fahrzeugbau Bau-, land- und  ..................... Reinraumtechnik Schiffsbau Sondermaschinenbau Antriebs- und Getriebetechnik Apparatebau
```

Answer (score 1):

A very quick method would be to remove the word `weiterlesen` from your final string with `branchenstring.replace('weiterlesen','')`.
This method obviously works only if it's always the same word i.e weiterlesen.

Comment: gladly it works in my case it works since it is always there. just a follow up question what would happen if there is not weiterlesen in the string?

Comment: Nothing, it would just move on.